# Doesn't work auto save custom fields in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, autosave

I'm using [Smashing Magazine](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/11/08/complete-guide-custom-post-types) tutorial step by step. But there is doesn't work auto save in my custom fields. After click publish and update button the fields are empty. How to resolve the issue.

```
 function my_custom_post_movie() {
  $labels = array(
    'name'               => _x( 'movies', 'post type general name' ),
    'singular_name'      => _x( 'movie', 'post type singular name' ),
    'add_new'            => _x( 'Add New', 'book' ),
    'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New movie' ),
    'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit movie' ),
    'new_item'           => __( 'New movie' ),
    'all_items'          => __( 'All movies' ),
    'view_item'          => __( 'View movie' ),
    'search_items'       => __( 'Search movies' ),
    'not_found'          => __( 'No movies found' ),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No movies found in the Trash' ), 
    'parent_item_colon'  => '',
    'menu_name'          => 'movies'
  );
  $args = array(
    'labels'        => $labels,
    'description'   => 'Holds our movies and movie specific data',
    'public'        => true,
    'menu_position' => 5,
    'supports'      => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' ),
    'has_archive'   => true,
  );
  register_post_type( 'movie', $args ); 
}
add_action( 'init', 'my_custom_post_movie' );

// Register Custom Taxonomies
function my_taxonomies_movie() {
  $labels = array(
    'name'              => _x( 'movie Categories', 'taxonomy general name' ),
    'singular_name'     => _x( 'movie Category', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
    'search_items'      => __( 'Search movie Categories' ),
    'all_items'         => __( 'All movie Categories' ),
    'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent movie Category' ),
    'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent movie Category:' ),
    'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit movie Category' ), 
    'update_item'       => __( 'Update movie Category' ),
    'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New movie Category' ),
    'new_item_name'     => __( 'New movie Category' ),
    'menu_name'         => __( 'movie Categories' ),
  );
  $args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'hierarchical' => true,
  );
  register_taxonomy( 'movie_category', 'movie', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'my_taxonomies_movie', 0 );

// Meta Box
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'movie_date_box' );
function movie_date_box() {
    add_meta_box( 
        'movie_date_box',
        __( 'movie date', 'myplugin_textdomain' ),
        'movie_date_box_content',
        'movie',
        'side',
        'high'
    );
}

function movie_date_box_content( $post ) {
  wp_nonce_field( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ), 'movie_date_box_content_nonce' );
  echo '<label for="movie_date"></label>';
  echo '<input type="text" id="movie_date" name="movie_date" placeholder="enter a date" />';
}

add_action( 'save_post', 'movie_date_box_save' );
function movie_date_box_save( $post_id ) {

   if( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return;

  if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['movie_date_box_content_nonce'], plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) )
  return;

  if ( 'page' == $_POST['post_type'] ) {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id ) )
    return;
  } else {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) )
    return;
  }
  $movie_date = $_POST['movie_date'];
  update_post_meta( $post_id, 'movie_date', $movie_date );
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your information is in fact being saved to the database, but it is not being called once the post has been submitted.

Change:

```
function movie_date_box_content( $post ) {
  wp_nonce_field( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ), 'movie_date_box_content_nonce' );
  echo '<label for="movie_date"></label>';
  echo '<input type="text" id="movie_date" name="movie_date" placeholder="enter a date" />';
}
```

to the following:

```
function movie_date_box_content( $post ) {
  wp_nonce_field( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ), 'movie_date_box_content_nonce' );
  echo '<label for="movie_date"></label>';
  echo '<input type="text" id="movie_date" name="movie_date" placeholder="enter a date" value="' . get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'movie_date', true ) . '" />';
}
```

You were missing `value="' . get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'movie_date', true ) . '"`

`get_post_meta()` calls the meta key `movie_date` from the database and shows it, if there is anything stored in that key.

Also change:

```
if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['movie_date_box_content_nonce'], plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) )
return;
```

to the following:

```
if ( !isset($_POST['movie_date_box_content_nonce']) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['movie_date_box_content_nonce'], plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) )
    return;
```

This checks to see if the nonce field is set and not **NULL**. It takes care of the **Undeclared Index** notice that shows up in the admin.